# How to keep the android monkey tool running? i.e not limiting the number of events

Tags: android, count, monkey

How do I tell the Android Monkey Tool that it should run for an infinite amount of events?

Comment: Refer to this [link.](http://1.yvanwang.sinaapp.com/?p=19). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the design of the monkey does not fit running an unlimited number of events.

When you provide parameters on your monkey command, it uses those to produce a script file, and then runs that script from the file.  Thus an unlimited number of events would require an infinitely long script file.